# Created path in SwiftUI doesn't animate

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am new in animating paths in SwiftUI. I tried to find an answer online but I couldn't find any solutions.

Here you have a video of a screen. I would love to have smooth animated background. I hope that you are gonna be able to help me.
Link: https://youtu.be/OBePXXxboZ8

Thank you so much for your help.

```
struct HomeView: View {
@State var index = true
@State var indexBattery = true
@State var batteryAnimationUp = 340
@State var batteryAnimationDown = 260
var body: some View {

    ZStack {
        Back(batteryAnimationUp: batteryAnimationUp, batteryAnimationDown: batteryAnimationDown)
        .offset(x: 0, y: 100)
            .onTapGesture {
                self.indexBattery.toggle()
                withAnimation(.linear(duration: 3)) {
                    if self.indexBattery{
                        self.batteryAnimationUp = 340
                        self.batteryAnimationDown = 260
                    } else {
                        self.batteryAnimationUp = 260
                        self.batteryAnimationDown = 340
                    }
                }
        }
        
        VStack {
            Image("Powered_logo")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
                
            HStack {
                if self.index {
                    LoginAllView(index: $index)
                        .transition(.moveAndFade)
                } else {
                    RegisterAllView(index: $index)
                        .transition(.moveAndFade)
                }
                
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

}

```
struct Back: View {
var batteryAnimationUp: Int
var batteryAnimationDown: Int
public var animatableData: AnimatablePair<Double, Double>{
    get{ AnimatablePair(Double(batteryAnimationUp), Double(batteryAnimationDown))}
    set{
        self.batteryAnimationUp = Int(newValue.first)
        self.batteryAnimationDown = Int(newValue.second)
    }
}
var body: some View{
    ZStack {
        Path { path in
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 300))
            path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 300), control: CGPoint(x: 50, y: batteryAnimationUp))
            path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 200, y: 300), control: CGPoint(x: 150, y: batteryAnimationDown))
            path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 300, y: 300), control: CGPoint(x: 250, y: batteryAnimationUp))
            path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 400, y: 300), control: CGPoint(x: 350, y: batteryAnimationDown))

            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 400, y: 1000))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1000))
            path.closeSubpath()
        }
        .fill(Color("Green2"))
        Path { path in
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 300))
            path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 300), control: CGPoint(x: 50, y: batteryAnimationUp))
            path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 200, y: 300), control: CGPoint(x: 150, y: batteryAnimationDown))
            path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 300, y: 300), control: CGPoint(x: 250, y: batteryAnimationUp))
            path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 400, y: 300), control: CGPoint(x: 350, y: batteryAnimationDown))
            path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 500, y: 300), control: CGPoint(x: 450, y: batteryAnimationUp))

            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 400, y: 1000))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1000))
            path.closeSubpath()
        }
        .fill(Color("Color"))
        .offset(x: -50, y: 0)
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Mark Moeykens has a tutorial on creating waves and animating them, that may be helpful to you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3ZHxF5Kwcqk

Comment: Yes it solved my problem. Thank you. https://youtu.be/kbXnxFNu6ZY Here is the result

Comment: That's awesome! I am glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get a smooth animation using an @State variable and an animation toggle which changes the X offset. This is animated smoothly with a linear animation with delay 3 and creates the desired animated effect. I also used a .onAppear to start the animation instantly but this can be changed. It also repeats forever but you can change how often it repeats or if you want it to reverse on completion. The offset varies between 0 and -200 which is the period of the wave.

Video Link here https://youtu.be/e5xY14lj3yc

```
struct HomeView: View {
  @State var index = true
  @State var indexBattery = true
  @State var batteryAnimation = false
  @State var batteryAnimationUp = 340
  @State var batteryAnimationDown = 260
  var body: some View {

    ZStack {
      Back(batteryAnimationUp: batteryAnimationUp, batteryAnimationDown: batteryAnimationDown, batteryAnimation: self.$batteryAnimation)
        .offset(x: 0, y: 100)
        .onAppear {
          self.batteryAnimation = true
        }
        
    }
  }
}

struct Back: View {
  var batteryAnimationUp: Int
  var batteryAnimationDown: Int
  @Binding var batteryAnimation: Bool
  public var animatableData: AnimatablePair<Double, Double>{
    get{ AnimatablePair(Double(batteryAnimationUp), Double(batteryAnimationDown))}
    set{
        self.batteryAnimationUp = Int(newValue.first)
        self.batteryAnimationDown = Int(newValue.second)
    }
  }
  var body: some View{
    ZStack {
        Path { path in
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 300))
            path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 300), control: CGPoint(x: 50, y: batteryAnimationUp))
            path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 200, y: 300), control: CGPoint(x: 150, y: batteryAnimationDown))
            path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 300, y: 300), control: CGPoint(x: 250, y: batteryAnimationUp))
            path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 400, y: 300), control: CGPoint(x: 350, y: batteryAnimationDown))
            path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 500, y: 300), control: CGPoint(x: 450, y: batteryAnimationUp))
            path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 600, y: 300), control: CGPoint(x: 550, y: batteryAnimationDown))
            path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 700, y: 300), control: CGPoint(x: 650, y: batteryAnimationUp))
            path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 800, y: 300), control: CGPoint(x: 750, y: batteryAnimationDown))

            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 400, y: 1000))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1000))
            path.closeSubpath()
        }
        .fill(Color.green)
        .offset(x: self.batteryAnimation ? -300 : -100, y: 0)
        .animation(
          Animation.linear(duration: 3)
            .repeatForever(autoreverses: false)
        )
      
        Path { path in
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 300))
            path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 300), control: CGPoint(x: 50, y: batteryAnimationUp))
            path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 200, y: 300), control: CGPoint(x: 150, y: batteryAnimationDown))
            path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 300, y: 300), control: CGPoint(x: 250, y: batteryAnimationUp))
            path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 400, y: 300), control: CGPoint(x: 350, y: batteryAnimationDown))
            path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 500, y: 300), control: CGPoint(x: 450, y: batteryAnimationUp))
            path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 600, y: 300), control: CGPoint(x: 550, y: batteryAnimationDown))
            path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 700, y: 300), control: CGPoint(x: 650, y: batteryAnimationUp))

            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 400, y: 1000))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1000))
            path.closeSubpath()
        }
        
        .fill(Color.blue)
        .offset(x: self.batteryAnimation ? 0 : -200, y: 0)
        .animation(
          Animation.linear(duration: 3)
            .repeatForever(autoreverses: false)
        )
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: This is a great animation and I am gonna use it :) but I wanted to move peaks up and down.

Comment: Could you be more specific about how you want to move them up and down? The easiest way to animate that I know of is to use ternary statements like .offset(x: boolean ? option1 : option2) . You should be able to do the same with the peaks for their x and y position

Comment: https://youtu.be/kbXnxFNu6ZY  Video above helped me. Here is my result. So much thank you for help

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out!! Good luck with the rest of your app!